# How can i select an object contained within another. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a script that adds several of these forms.

```
var html = '<div class="equipment_row">' +
'<img src="'+base_url+'verkstad/icons/icon-'+type+'.png"/>' +
'<input class="eq_amount" type="text" value="'+amount+'" />' +
'<input class="eq_artnr" type="text" value="'+artnr+'" />' +
'<input class="eq_text" type="text" value="'+text+'" />' +
'<input class="eq_price" type="text" value="'+price+'" />' +
'<img src="'+base_url+'verkstad/icons/eq_delete.png" class="eq_delete_img"/>' +
</div>';
$('#equipment_container').append(html);
```

Then when the user hits "save" I want it to collect all these values in an array

```
var eq_array = Array();
var obj;
$('.equipment_row').each(function(){
obj = new Object();
obj.amount = ??? 
obj.artnr = ???
obj.text = ???
obj.price = ???
eq_array.push(obj);
});
var dataString = $.toJSON(eq_array);
alert(dataString);
```

How can I access the containing input fields in "equipment_row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.equipment_row').each(function(i, e){
obj = new Object();
obj.amount = $('.eq_amount', e).val();
```

and so on..

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot easier to wrap it all in a form element and do `$(form).serialize();`

Answer (score 1):

i'm surprised there is no names on your inputs, but only a class.

```
var eq_array = new Array(); // = [];
$('.equipment_row').each( function () {
    var obj = new Object(); // = {};
    $('input, select', this).each( function () {
        obj[$(this).attr('class')] = this.value;
    });
    eq_array.push(obj);
});
```

note with this your array will look like

```
[ { eq_amout: 2113,
    eq_artnr: ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
obj.amount = $(this).find('.eq_amount');
```

and stuff like that.